# How To Delete Overlapping Lines in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to remove everything outside the lighter gray rectangle, i.e. remove the 2 overhanging lines from the black rhomboid/parallelogram.

Is there a good way to do this in Illustrator?

[image]

Comment: Look into the pathfinder options.

Comment: Which version of AI are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create another rectangle with the same size as the light grey then create clipping mask. Or you can use Pathfinder to cut out the lines with the new rectangle you just created above.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Use the Shape Builder tool. It's a newer tool in CC, and not a lot of people know about it or how to use it.

Select both objects, then select the Shape Builder tool.  Holding down the Option key (Mac - probably the Alt Key on PC) and click in the area you want to delete.  When you hover over it, the area affected will get a grey hash pattern over it.

Adobe has a pretty decent tutorial here: https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/creating-shapes-shape-builder-tool.html